# How to mimic Giordano's Pizza SAUCE? (Part 2)

Tags: sauce, pizza, restaurant-mimicry, deep-dish-pizza

I am trying to mimic [Giordano's pizza](http://www.giordanos.com/) at home, as stated in [part 1](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/25475/6279) I need to learn how to make both the crust and the SAUCE. I think I can manage the rest...

I am looking for advice on how to make a pizza sauce to mimic Giordano's.

I can make a 'pretty good' pizza sauce, but I can't seem to get the seasoning quite right to match Giordano's. I would call garlic the most pronounce flavor, but I can't seem to meter the seasonings 'just right'. In my attempts the garlic either overwhelms the flavor or is not as pronounced as I think it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grocer doesn't have Pastorelli Pizza Sauce in stock, have him order some for you. They supply the pizza industry and will allow you to make an authentic Chicago style pizza.

Comment: This answer seems like spam at first glance but I totally agree - I have not found a better pizza sauce available to the public (I'm in the Chicago area) that comes close to being as good as Pastorelli's.  I ship it to my brother who lives out of state.